# UFT is not recording in chrome

Tags: hp-uft

Chrome 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (32-bit).

UFT 14.03

Click Record in UFT tool bar.

Performed operations.

Click Stop.

UFT did not add any steps.

Micro focus functional testing agent is enabled in chrome extension:

[image]

How can I record in chrome using UFT?

Comment: UFT should work on Chrome 70. Do you have "Record and run on any browser" selected from in your web Record And Run settings?

Answer (score 0):

Please downgrade to chrome 62. 
Please make sure that the UFT Extension in Chrome is enabled.
Please check that zoom in chrome is at 100% before you click on record in UFT.

You can check that by setting chrome://extensions/ URL in your Chrome Browser and make sure that the UFT extension exists and enabled.

Let me know if any of these helps.
Enjoy Testing!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can see from Microfocus site, UFT 14.03 supports Chrome 70 Beta version. 
Refer : https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/PAM/UFT_14.xx_PAM.pdf (Refer Page 11/34)

Did you currently updated your browser? If yes, surely you can downgrade to previous one as a bypass solution. But I would suggest you to kindly get in touch with Microfocus team  by opening a ticket and once you get the resolution you can surely  turn of auto upgrade of Google chrome browser.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history 
Chrome 71 v Beta is also there and 72 dev in progress. Its better you keep auto update off to avoid such problems in future.
Happy Coding. :-)